# linq check if matches null or selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am checking to see if items already match whats in my MSSQL DB. I am using LINQ to update records. I would like to know how i can check if an item is equal to d_0_2 or if its equal to null/empty. How would i go about doing this?

below is my existing code, which partially works. but is failing due to the null/Empty

```
 if (updateProduct.studioId == Convert.ToInt32(d_0_2.SelectedValue)) { }
 else { updateProduct.studioId = Convert.ToInt32(d_0_2.SelectedValue);}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need your code to do if `updateProduct.studioId` is NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string value = d_0_2.SelectedValue.ToString();
// what if SelectedValue is empty or null?
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return;
// what if product is null?
if (updateProduct != null)
    return;

if (updateProduct.studioId != null &&
    updateProduct.studioId == Convert.ToInt32(value))
{
    // you have product and its id equal to d_0_2.SelectedValue
}
else
{
    // studioId not equal to to d_0_2.SelectedValue
    updateProduct.studioId = Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you question correctly, but you want to check if item is null or if not is it studioId equal to `d_0_2.SelectedValue`

```
if (updateProduct == null)
{
     //create new update product
}
else if (updateProduct.studioId != Convert.ToInt32(d_0_2.SelectedValue))
{
     updateProduct.studioId = Convert.ToInt32(d_0_2.SelectedValue);
}
```